# How to validate minified CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, minify

When i attach my CSS files separately everything works fine in IE ,However when i combine my CSS into one file and minifiy it everything starts to break .

Is there a way i can validate the minified css

Answer (score 1):

While compressing the css code, you should be aware that spaces at critical places like between to class calls and media queries are important... Specially for IE version...

Use [CSS Compressor](http://www.csscompressor.com/) for minify css in custom form...

And then you can valid it with [W3C Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I can see, is that combining all CSS's is overwriting some of your styles, that's why you see things breaking. You should have a re-look at all your styles and see if they are not being overwritten.